# New York State - NY Tax on Foreign Sourced Income for NY Non-Resident

Tags: united-states, taxes, income

I live in Connecticut (file as CT Resident) .. Work in NYC ((file as NY Non-Resident)

Question:  Can NY State tax any income that I earn while in Germany ?

I understand that the United States taxes "worldwide" income for US citizens / residents -
However - *** as I am a NY State "Non-Resident" ***  ... does  NY get to tax my Germany-sourced income ?

Thank you...  ( reply to C-Tax)

Answer (score 1):

For Non-Resident filers, New York taxes New York-sourced income. That includes:

> - real or tangible personal property located in New York State
>     (including certain gains or losses from the sale or exchange of an
>     interest in an entity that owns real property in New York State);
> - services performed in New York State;
> - a business, trade, profession, or occupation carried on in New York State; and
> - a New York S corporation in which you are a shareholder (including
>     installment income from an IRC 453 transaction).

There are some exclusions as well. It is all covered in the [instructions to form IT-203](http://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/2013/inc/it203i_2013.pdf).

However, keep in mind that "filing" as non-resident doesn't make you non-resident. If you spend 184 days or more in New York State, and you have a place to stay there - you **are** resident. See [definitions here](http://www.tax.ny.gov/pit/file/pit_definitions.htm). Even if you don't actually *live* there and consider yourself a CT resident.